# Issue while fetching file from storage path in Blade: Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to set the file path which is present in below folder.

> storage/Asset/Media/1/FileName

For that, I wrote below code.

```
<img class="img-responsive avatar-view" 
src={!! 
        URL("/storage/Asset/Media/1/FileName.png)  
    !!}
>
```

This produces below path

```
http://localhost/AdminSystem/public/storage/Asset/Media/1/filename.png
```

and my file is in below path

```
http://localhost/AdminSystem/storage/Asset/Media/1/filename.png
```

Please suggest if I missed anything to get file from storage path

Comment: It should be inside the public before you create another folder like `/storage/something/test.jpg`

Comment: The paths indicate a malconfigured webserver. Your public folder should be the DocumentRoot, and the public/storage should be a symlink from `php artisan storage:link`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem for details.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this method,

```
storage_path().'/Asset/Media/1/FileName.png'
```

means

```
<img class="img-responsive avatar-view" src="{!!storage_path().'/Asset/Media/1/FileName.png'!!}">
```

Comment: It shows path like below. http://localhost/AdminSystem/public/C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/storage/Asset/Media/1/filename.png

Comment: can you share code, complete line, that what you have written? this path `/Asset/Media/1/FileName.png` is located in your storage directory, right ?

Comment: this path /Asset/Media/1/FileName.png is located in your storage directory, right ? Yes

Comment: Here is the complete line `<img src={!! storage_path("Asset/Media/") . $User->UserContactInfoID . "/" . $User->UniqueFileName  !!} >`

Comment: whats the reason that you keeping user images inside `storage` directory instead `Public` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The best way to fetch any file from storage is you first define the root of this file and use it every time.

For example in Route.php you can define it in following way.

```
define('MEDIA_ROOT', '/storage/Asset/Media');
```

Whenever you want to show it there use this code:

```
 <img src="{{ MEDIA_ROOT.'/1/FileName.png' }}"/>
```

Comment: Not working, I got the path like below. "MEDIA_ROOT" 1/filename.png   Yes, I declared the reference in route.php

Comment: You want me to write your updated code `<?php $img = MEDIA_ROOT.'/1/FileName.png'; ?>` in blade? I meant, Is it recommended to write variables in blade?